# random selection from a table

Tags: php, symfony, select, random

I need help with the problem of random selection from a table. The request returns random rows indeed, but it returns the same result every time, nothing changes. Here is the code. any help?

```
$count = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->select('COUNT(u)')
    ->from('BPQuizzBundle:Question','b')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleScalarResult();

$qb2=$this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb2->select('b')
    ->from('BPQuizzBundle:Question','b')
    ->where('b.id <=:rand')
    ->join('b.module','l', 'WITH', 'l.id = :id')
    ->setParameters(array('rand' => rand(1,$count),'id' => $module->getId()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not the best way to handle random elements. I would rather get all possible ids and pick a random id from the resulting table. That might be better.

Or other way of doing it : setting a limit of 1 result and adding a rand on the starting element.

```
$query
    ->setFirstResult($randomNumber)
    ->setMaxResults(1);
```